# C# Blazor server app - Updating Scoped DI object at runtime

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, blazor-server-side

we are using the C# Blazor server app and adding the scoped dependency injection, and initialization of the class `CurrentRequestContext` on the program startup class. Once the user is authenticated, we update the `CurrentRequestContext` object with the authenticated user.

```
 public static void AppScopeObjects(this IServiceCollection services){
    services.AddScoped<UIDIWrapper>(x => new UIDIWrapper()
    {
        PreventDataOverwriteService = x.GetService<IPreventDataOverwriteService>(),
        CurrentContext = new CurrentRequestContext()
    });
}
```

in the login form we are injecting

```
 [Inject]
 protected UIDIWrapper Wrapper { get; set; } = default!;
```

Once authenticated we update the value

```
 Wrapper.CurrentContext.LoggedInUser = aUser;
```

The value is lost once we navigate to another form.
My understanding of the dependency injection is since it's scoped it will get called once the new user requests the app for the first time. So I am instantiating for the first time once the authentication is done then I am updating the value and reusing it everywhere.  But the value is lost while navigating to another form.

So where am I missing something here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's `IPreventDataOverwriteService`?  What's `Wrapper.CurrentContext`?  You are doing something because this will work if you implement it correctly.  You should have a simple setter method for a private setter on `LoggedInUser` which you can then put a breakpoint on and see who's doing the damage.

Comment: But the value is lost while navigating to another form---are you sending httprequest?If yes,it would be another instance of  UIDIWrapper.Could you show us a minial example that could reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set up the app in the following way.

```
Login Component  - Follows the Empty Layout 
Other App Components - Follows the Main Layout
UIDIWrapper  - Empty Object is injected as Scoped
App. razor default layout - Main layout.
```

The app is navigated to the component inside the main layout after the user successfully logs in, and the UIDIWrapper  is updated to empty object.

So, a new UIWrapper object is created after navigating to the inside component.
The solution would be the following.

> I have to pass a UserID (Encrypted) to the other component and refill the  current context

or

> Read it from the Auth provider and refill the current context.

So, finally, I have used Auth Provider to read the username and refill the session after navigating to the Home Page.